# Executar um bloco de execução (SQL Server) no Doctrine + ZF2

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine

Preciso executar um bloco de execução SQL (SQL SERVER) em um Repository no Doctrine. Meu ambiente esta com ZF2 + Doctrine 2. Já li algumas coisas sobre `ResultSetMapping`no Doctrine, mas não consegui.

Código:

```
public function teste() {
        $connection = $this->_em->getConnection();
        $sql = "DECLARE @Test AS dbo.DataTempTransactions;
                INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('015.004.000',100,'015A')
                DECLARE @DATE datetime
                SET @DATE = GETDATE()
                EXEC ONCode.dbo.TmSp_Exit @Test, @mnfdate = @DATE
                SELECT * FROM ONTest.dbo.OBTN";
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

        return $stmt->execute();
}
```

Estou usando no bloco de um execução um Tipo definido pelo usuário - *`dbo.DataTempTransactions`* - ([Use Table-Valued Parameters (Database Engine)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)), não sei se influencia em alguma coisa.

Obrigado desde já.